# quora crawler using selenium and phantomjs, can't get stats info

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use `python` to crawler quora with `selenium` and `phantomjs`. I crawler the question page using the following code:

```
# coding=utf-8

# Created by lruoran on 17-1-29

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'/home/lruoran/software/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
driver.get('https://www.quora.com/Who-is-Roger-Federer')
cnt_answers = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='answer_count']").text.encode('utf-8').strip().split()[0]
if cnt_answers[-1].isdigit():
    cnt_answers = int(cnt_answers)
else:
    cnt_answers = int(cnt_answers[:-1])
print("problem:{:s}".format(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1").text.encode('utf-8')))
print('the number of answers:{:d}'.format(cnt_answers))
try:
    print("the number of follow:{:s}".format(
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//a[contains(@class,'FollowerListModalLink')]").text.encode('utf-8')))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

However,with the `xpath` : `//a[contains(@class,'FollowerListModalLink')]` . I can't get the number of followers of [the problem](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-Roger-Federer). But I test the `xpath` with `xpath` helper, it can find the element successfully.

The result of xpath helper is in this picture-

[image]

Comment: I can see number of followers in `Firefox`, but there is no `Question stats` data displayed on `Chrome`. Same issue could be in `PhantomJS`

Comment: I have solve this problem by myself. Some elements can only be seen when  you log in. So you should log in first to get all elements in the problem page.